# Option to disable keyboard shortcuts in WMD

Tags: feature-request, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Safari because it supports most of Emacs keyset in textareas. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow breaks that. (Especially annoying are **strong text** (C-b, left-arrow), followed shortly by `enter code here` (C-k, cut line).)

Anyway, I would like to request a preference to turn off the keyboard shortcuts.

Note: In another question, somebody mentioned disabling Javascript, but that sounds like it would break the rest of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Dupe. Many times over.

Comment: I searched meta stackoverflow and didn't see anything. Where the previous requests not migrated from uservoice? How do I find out the answer (if any) to those requests?

Comment: I would really appreciate it too, since ATL-GR + '=' (which correponds to } on my azerty keyboard) produces the 'ctrl-k' effect... which is annoyous for a C++ user !!

Comment: These are called "access keys" and the HTML attribute used to implement them is called "accesskey".  You might like to add this as a tag.

Comment: +1 for preferences setting to disable accesskeys in textboxes!