# Standardized formatting in comments and keyboard shortcuts for this formatting

Tags: feature-request, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting Keyboard Shortcuts for Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14756/formatting-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments)

[Allowing Ctrl+k in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75623/allowing-ctrlk-in-comments) has been ignored for a while, but I wanted to extend the feature request.

That question and its answers asks for the keyboard shortcuts for [supported formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities), which include:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> - Bold
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> - Italic
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> - Link
- <kbd>CRTL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> - Code Block

I propose that we add the following features:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> - Graphic

  - Opens the image uploader, allowing imgur links to be inserted [without resorting to editing the post to get the WMD uploader](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/730/whats-the-proper-way-to-upload-images).  Rather than inserting the `![...][1]` markdown, though, it would  surround `[selected text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/image.png)` with the markdown for a titled link insert the bare link to the image.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> - Undo

  - Should be obvious....
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> - Redo

  - Should also be obvious....

And also that we add the following standardized formatting and associated shortcuts:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> - Block Quote

  - Inserts `*""*`, or surrounds `*"selected text"*` with this standard quote formatting.
    [image]
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> - Ordered (numbered) List

  - Inserts (1) the next number enclosed in parentheses (2) every time (3) the shortcut is used.  Should automatically correct numbering problems. 
    [image]
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> - Unordered (bullet) List

  - Unordered lists don't work very well in comments, but you could use () bare parentheses, • a bullet character, or ☃ some other character or character sequence to indicate a list. 
    [image]
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> - Heading

  - Surround `***Selected Text:***` in bold italic formatting or add the sequence `***:***` if no text is selected.
    [image]

These standardized formattings would improve consistency, save time, ease readability (if used appropriately), and make the site look better.

This leaves only <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> (Horizontal Line), which really doesn't make sense in a field that doesn't allow line breaks.

Comment: I considered making [CTRL]-[G] a separate feature request, but took a move from my leaders and added some earmarks...

Comment: This definitely seems like overkill for comments... What are you doing putting images (or links to images) in comments in the first place?

Comment: @Cody - _"This definitely seems like overkill for comments "_ - True, but (1) we've all seen examples of most of these formats typed out in comments, (2) we're already familiar with the shortcuts from the WMD editor so it's nothing new, and (3) as I said, it would improve consistency, save time, ease readability, and make the site look better.

Comment: @Cody - _"What are you doing putting images (or links to images) in comments in the first place?"_ - Um, I'm making comments, some of which require images?  I spend most all my time at Electrical Engineering, where schematics and PCB photos are common.

Comment: re: Possible duplicate: Whoops, I was coming from [Allowing Ctrl+k in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75623/allowing-ctrlk-in-comments) and that question wasn't even linked as related.  The Greasemonkey script is useful, and I could extend that, but [Jeff's comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14756/formatting-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments#comment-50769) makes me think this is unlikely to happen.  I think my post adds some additional content that's not present in the dupe; may I edit some of my suggestions into that post?

Comment: I'm a little worried that having CTRL+O as ordered list will conflict with the Open function in most browsers. I would maybe have that hotkey be CTRL+SHIFT+L just to avoid confusion. For much the same reason, I would avoid CTRL+N.

Comment: Also related: [To have CTRL-B to make text bold in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5886/to-have-ctrl-b-to-make-text-bold-in-comments/6906#6906) and the associated Stack Apps script [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/2103/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-comments), which does [CTRL]-[B], [CTRL]-[I], and [CTRL]-[K]

Comment: @AarthiDevanathan: True, but that already happens in the WMD editor.  If we change to CTRL+SHIFT+L, we should also change WMD.

Comment: @KevinVermeer Is there a potential alternative? CTRL+P or something?

Comment: @AarthiDevanathan: That's "Print" on most platforms.  In my browser (Chrome on Mac 10.6), I find that (the equivalents of) CTRL-ACDEFGHJLMNOPQRSTVWXYZ are all taken. The only letter shortcuts which aren't used are B, U, and I.  I'd rather have the web application (SO) determine what the shortcuts should be in this context, and tab out of the input box to get normal OS/browser shortcuts when necessary.

Comment: @KevinVermeer Oh wow, I didn't realize. Well, if the comment boxes *can* have independent shortcut key options then the ones you've listed should be fine. I just felt like I should point out a potential conflict :)

Comment: "which really doesn't make sense in a field that doesn't allow line breaks" pssst... half of these suggestions don't make sense in comments for that exact reason! If you want you can edit the first 4 into the dupe, but it's in obvious territory for me.

Answer (score 3):

No, no, no.

In fact, I would like the editor to stop hijacking the control-k mean "kill to end of line" mapping the firefox gives me and my emacs reflexes.

Comment: I understand that you disagree, but the issue of the editor hijacking your emacs sequences has been brought up [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/option-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-wmd), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys), and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47316/please-do-not-hijack-command-q). If you don't like the editor behavior in the first place, then disable it and don't prevent those of us who like it from using it in comments!