# Ctrl+B in an answer text field on OS X makes text bold instead of moving cursor back

Tags: bug, edits

For most programs on OS X (as well as emacs) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> causes the text cursor to move back a character. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow's answer editor hijacks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and uses it for bolding text. This is, of course, a very understandable decision, but it breaks a standard UI convention for OS X users, which naturally leads to a number of mistakes and minor annoyances. For example, I added and removed `**strong text**` perhaps a dozen times while writing this bug report.

Is there any way you all can change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to **<kbd>Command</kbd>** + <kbd>B</kbd> for OS X users? In addition to fixing a usability problem, using <kbd>Command</kbd> will make the shortcut more in line with other OS X shortcuts. It'll also make answering/asking question a little less annoying.

Comment: Here's a related discussion, mostly arguing for the use of `ctrl` instead of `command`: [On Mac based browser Command-L should select the address bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100349/on-mac-based-browser-command-l-should-select-the-address-bar)

Comment: Others would say that's a feature request: [Option to disable keyboard shortcuts in WMD](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/option-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-wmd).

Answer (score -4):

And thus they invented <kbd>←</kbd>

Is it that hard to press an arrow?

I see your issue and I hear how it can be a problem, but can't you just press the back arrow?

Comment: I used to the back arrow all the time.  Then after years of bending my wrist into a J shape hundreds of times day, I started getting wrist pains.  I think created an [AutoHotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/) [script](https://github.com/Xavi-/Keyboard-Remapper) that moved the arrows to the home row and the pain went a way.  I then bought a mac and my AutoHotkeys script didn't work anymore.  Luckily osx support emac style navigation everywhere, which I now use everywhere and pain hasn't returned.  So, why don't I use the back arrow?  Because I don't like pain.

Comment: @Xavi NOTED. :-)

Comment: I don't have many karma points, but arrow keys breaks the typing flow and most importantly the above the reason of wrist pain.